# Control when menu disappears in UISplitViewController

Tags: objective-c, iphone-sdk-3.2, uisplitviewcontroller

I've got a UISplitViewController set up and working nicely. When a user touches a row, it pops out an indented row of options, which the user can then select to update the detail view. The only issue is that in portrait mode the menu disappears after selecting one of the non-indented rows, so the user has to hit the menu button again to display the menu and select the indented option.

Is there a way to tell the menu not to disappear when tapping one of the non-indented rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Um, wow. Can't believe I posted this question - it was so long since I set up the popoverController I forgot that I dismissed it manually with -dismissPopoverAnimated: